# bootstrap nav-list collapse hover issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I can't seem to get the hover to function properly (highlight the list item) on a nav-header when inside a nav-list which I has a collapse control as well. Note the nav-header item has to have a link to a page as well as the collapse control, hence the span.

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
<li class="nav-header">
    <span>
        <a href="/" title=""><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a>
        <span class="caret pull-right" data-target="#test" data-toggle="collapse"></span>
    </span>
    <ul class="nav nav-list collapse in" id="test" >
        <li><a href="/ticket_list.cfm" title="Show list of tickets">Open Tickets</a></li>
        <li><a href="/account/" title="Edit user accounts">Accounts / Community</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/awjreynolds/2Aucc/3/

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: it seems to work fine here on chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `<span>`tag is preventing the highlight effect because the selectors that control these styles are `.nav-list > li > a` and `.nav-list > li > a:hover`.
So you can adapt your markup or reproduce that styles with selectors that fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the above the following css fixes the issue: 
`.nav > li > span:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #EEE;
}
.nav > li > span {
display: block;
}
.nav-list > li > span> a {
text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-list > li > span{
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.nav-list > li > span {
padding: 3px 15px;
}`
​[link](http://jsfiddle.net/awjreynolds/2Aucc/14/)

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue of hover styling not working in a nav-list containing a `<span>`.  Besides the issues raised by the original post, the `.active` styling doesn't work at all if you `<li>` contains a `<span>`.  I expanded on css that awjr arrived at to get this version which handles the `class="active"` case.

Here's the working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sazerac08/bKSJs/4/

```
/* fix bootsrap nav-list containing a span */
.nav > li > span:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #EEE;
}
.nav-list > .active > span, .nav-list > .active > span:hover, .nav-list > .active > span:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #0088cc;
}
.nav-list > .active > span > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.nav > li > span {
    display: block;
}
.nav-list > li > span > a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-list > li > span {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.nav-list > li > span {
    padding: 3px 15px;
}
```